# Is the open mapping theorem true for all complete metrizable topological vector spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

Recall that the open mapping theorem is true for Banach spaces. Furthermore, it is also true for Frechet spaces, which are complete metric spaces(with extra properties). It makes me wonder whether we can say that open mapping theorem applies to all complete metrizable topological vector spaces, since the key ingredient Baire category theorem certainly applies to all complete metric spaces and the norm in the proof of Banach spaces can be adapted to metric hopefully.

Comment: The Banach space theorem applies to _linear_ maps...

Comment: I am sorry, I should certainly say a complete metrizable topological vector space.

Comment: Any completely metrizable locally convex topological vector space is Frechet.

Comment: That is true, but what about complete metrizable topological vector space? It is not necessarily locally convex.